Ubuntu 20.04 not recognizing internal hard drives
Trying to dual boot ubuntu 20.04 on a windows 11 machine, but the installer doesn't recognize my hard drives and only shows the usb. For some reason I was able to install ubuntu 22.04 and 24.04 with no issues, but I need ubuntu 20.04 in specific. Also when I interact with the installer at the Installation type screen, it gives me an internal error that says: "ubiquity crashed with TypeError in partman_dialog(): argument of 'NoneType' is not iterable".
Any tips?

Good chance the ISO used to make the boot media was bad. Did you verify it before making the boot device? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview

@David I did, everything seemed to check out.
sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS 2>&1 | grep OK
ubuntu-20.04.6-desktop-amd64.iso: OK

perhaps explain why 20.04 is needed in preference to 22.04 or 24.04 which you indicate seem to work with no issues. [edit] in to your question - don't add to the comment trail which is there for us to ask you questions. It may then be possible to understand the issue more clearly.
